# LTC4366 killing MOSFETs

Tags: surge-protection, over-voltage-protection

I designed a circuit around LTC4366 as per the picture below. However numerous MOSFETs have been damaged and become useless.

Mosfets used : STH12N120K5-2; IXFT50N85XVH; STW13NK100Z - All are rated to above 800V and 12A

The Load is operated with 380VDC and can handle 450VDC MAX (the threshold in the circuit is set to 420VDC). The power supply can deliver 800VDC if it fails (and this is what I want to protect the load from)

1) If the Gate Cap (Cg) is 3.3nF the Vout never goes up. The circuit behaves as if it was in the protected mode.

2) If the Gate Cap (Cg) is 10pF the circuit works and turns off the MOSFET when the input voltage reaches approx. 420V. However if I set the power supply to 550VDC, the LTC4366 resets the failure every 9 seconds and after a few cycles the MOSFET simply dies and shows a short between Drain and Source

[image]

Comment: What are you asking specifically? I suggest you look at the "MOSFET Selection" section of the DS carefully. Linear's surge-stoppers run MOSFETs in the ohmic region. If your MOSFET is meant for switching and not linear operation, it will die quickly. Check that your application is in the SOA of the MOSFET.

Comment: HI BB. Even with the mosfet recommended by the datasheet the situation persists.

Comment: The SOA Safe Operating Area (ontime versus power dissipation) may be **violated** as the FET attempts to charge that 0.47uF cap. Or you may have oscillation. What bypass cap do you have across the IC?

Comment: There is no bypass cap as per the datasheet recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Just looking through the design procedure for this IC, you seem to have chosen an Rss that is at least a factor of 2 too high. The design calls for a current of 250µA through Rss while keeping the IC biased. 250µA through 2MΩ is higher than your supply voltage.

This IC also works in an intermittent linear regulator modality when in fault condition, so your pass-FET would be taking the brunt of the power to drop the voltage to an acceptable level. If you did not take this extra power into account (intermittent as it may be), your FETs will blow.

Attempting to drive a capacitance to ground of 3.3nF within 1ms (or even the 1nF+ capacitance of your NFETs) would require on the order of 200µA, with your 12.5MΩ supply resistor this implies a voltage drop of 2500V. The C3 charge pump is there to reduce this problem, but this only helps when pulling the gate down, not in start-up.

Comment: Hi Edgar. Really appreciated your comment. I have read the datasheet entirely again and can't seem to find the proper values of resistors and capacitors to accommodate the requirements: Vin(min) 380V, Vreg 430V and Vin(max) 800V. By any chance, are you aware of any spreadsheet that calculates the values?

Comment: The data sheet has a design suggestion for when the value of Rss cannot be satisfied directly. In page 13 they add a PNP transistor to provide the bias current. But just skimming through it, it does not seem to me that the Rss value is that hard to satisfy. You might need to relax the design constraints somewhat. And R2 does not seem to be that critical.

Comment: As for the Cg cap, the datasheet calls for a minimum value of 2nF so I used the one I had in hand (3.3nF) and the chip doesn't seem to start with such a high value so that I had to use 10pF that is 100x smaller than the recommended.

Comment: @JG_Bozza if you don’t select a proper Rss to bias the IC it should not be surprising that it does not meet specifications.